# Magento redirecting secure www to secure non www

Tags: magento, redirect, https

My site used to auto redirect from http://www.petpresto.com.au/ to http://petpresto.com.au/ which was great. Both addresses resolved fine, worked perfectly, and redirected as needed.

Then I decided to change the entire site over to secure https.

Now both http://www.petpresto.com.au/ and http://petpresto.com.au/ redirect to https://petpresto.com.au/ (I think this is done by Magento automatically - which is great) but https://www.petpresto.com.au/ does not resolve at all and I don't know how to make it also redirect to https://petpresto.com.au/?

My SSL cert is valid for both www and non www.

Answer (score 0):

hellp,please the code in htacess file this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1
```

Also,you secure url must be https://petpresto.com.au/.Please check this in admin setting `system>configuration>General>Web`

Comment: Checked secure URL and it is correct. Also added code to .htaccess with no effect. I had previously edited .htaccess file for speed improvements so I hope those edits are not conflicting with your edit? Find copy here: http://pastebin.com/W5rgT08t